# Querying a database record from flowfile content to retrive data using apache-nifi

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

My scenario is as followed. 
From one process I retrieve data from a table.

```
id,user_name
1,sachith
2,nalaka
```

I need to retrieve account details from `account_details` table for these `id`s.

I have tried to use various database related processors. But none of them support `flowfile` content.

How can I retrieve records only for these `id`?

Answer (score 2):

use below:

```
ExecuteSQL( account_details) 
    -> convertAvroToJSON 
       -> EvaluateJsonPath 
           ->AttributesToJson
```

( here you take only id and ignore test)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `LookupRecord` using a `DatabaseRecordLookupService` controller service. That should allow you to use the `id` field to look up additional fields from a database and add them to the outgoing records. This is a common "enrichment" pattern, where the lookups can be done against databases, CSV files, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain with a sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html)** processor to query data from flowfiles. You will need to set a reader and a writer inside this processor to open your file properly and write as well. To create a query, you must create a property with the name of the query and put the query itself as the value for this property. After that, you can create an output stream for this property.

The query syntax is `Apache Calcite`.
You can find further explanation [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html)